# Enabling UPU S18 4-State Barcode Scanner Support for Zebra TC57 Device Using EMDK

Tags: android, xamarin.android, motorola-emdk, zebra-scanners

How can I enable UPU S18 4-State Barcode scanner support for a Zebra TC57 device using the EMDK (Enterprise Mobility Development Kit)? I need to integrate this functionality into my application to scan UPU S18 4-State barcodes, but I'm unsure of the necessary steps and code modifications required. Could someone provide guidance or sample code on how to accomplish this?

Please find the barcode specification.
https://help.accusoft.com/BarcodeXpress/v13.6/BxActiveX/UPU_S18_4-State_Barcode.html

This is my current code setup. (This is Xamarin Android code). I am supporting both native and Android.

```
if (null != _mScanner && _mScanner.IsEnabled && !_mScanner.IsReadPending)
                {
                    //EMDK: Configure the scanner settings
                    var config = _mScanner.GetConfig();
                    if (null != config)
                    {
                        config.ScanParams.DecodeLEDFeedback = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.Code39.Enabled = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.Code93.Enabled = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.Code128.Enabled = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.Ean8.Enabled = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.Pdf417.Enabled = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.I2of5.Enabled = true;
                        config.ReaderParams.ReaderSpecific.ImagerSpecific.CharacterSetSelection = ScannerConfig.CharacterSet.Iso88591;
                        _mScanner.SetConfig(config);
                        return Task.FromResult(true);
                    }
                }
```